# Raspberry pi 2 - Check if anything is connected to the pin

Tags: rpi.gpio

I am making a game with the raspberry pi, which can be played for 1-4 players. I just wanted to know, if there is a way to count the number of buttons connected. I want to determine the number of players by the number of inputs connected.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use GPIOs that do not have other specialized purposes by default (e.g., the I2C bus pins) then they are all inputs when the system starts up.  Further, your application can set whatever range of inputs it wants as inputs explicitly.  It then just needs to poll that given set and register each one as attached if it is being driven high or if its state goes high momentarily (i.e., the attached control use a pull-down or something, and the player does something with the control to make it clear it is there).

In the latter case (waiting for a quick high), you then need to select either a time period or second kind of signal (from an input, from the keyboard, whatever) to indicate all applicable controls should have registered themselves by now and the game can begin.

Put another way:

> I just wanted to know, if there is a way to count the number of buttons connected

Yes.  Either:

- Make the button a pull up *which includes its own external connection and resistor to the 3.3V rail*, in which case only HIGH inputs would have such a button circuit attached.
- Make the button a pull down and wait for the user to push the button to indicate it is in play, with a defined waiting period or second style of "opening bell" signal.

Personally I think the second option is better, because you can then use inputs with internal pull-downs, I think pull downs make more sense in general, and it makes things more flexible in that you could leave controls attached and *not* use them for a particular game.

Also if you make the opening bell signal a second click on one input you give mean spirited players the opportunity to cut someone slower out ;P

Comment: Thanks, you summed up very well! I will try these for sure.